# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting after amd driver install

Tags: boot, grub2, vmware

I had a perfectly running system running in vmplayer.  I had installed other packages and other items, updated the OS and a bit more with absolutely no problem.  Suddenly I want the graphics card to work better and boom right on reboot after package install of amd pro driver 17 the machine will not boot.  It gets stuck in the /dev/sda1/ clean ...  I have tried the shift to grub and recover with no avail.  I would love to know if I can uninstall that package from the grub menu?  Or if there is anything else I can do.  I would normally just wipe and redo but I have stuff on that drive I cannot loose.  Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of you are using wrong drivers. AMD drivers are not made to run in virtualbox (or vmware)

Now if you can shift between virtual terminals using `alt+ctrl+f2` `alt+ctrl+f3` ..etc and log in then you can remove those drivers and install vesa drivers back.

if you can't shift between virtual terminals then last option is boot from live USB or image . any live image will work

now boot from live image and mount /dev/sda1 to the /mnt with command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1
```

now change the root to /mnt with

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

of if you are uing arch-live-iso then

```
sudo arch-chroot /mnt
```

now you can uninstall those drivers or whatever culprit packages from terminal and install vesa drivers (if these was because of drivers)

Comment: I will try this.  By the way I have tried all sorts of things to get back into the os itself with no avail.  I am using the iso from ubuntu to create the machine, can I mount that?  Also are you meaning mount this from grub in the root console?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @CharleyGeorge You can ISO from Ubuntu but I don't have experince with much . arch-iso provides much better tools for situation like this . Also arch-iso's size like 400 to 500 MBs

Comment: @CharleyGeorge  You said `are you meaning mount this from grub in the root console` NO Sir . just boot from live ISO and follow steps that tell you Sir.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help bu nothing is working I guess I am SOL.  Oh boy I really have some stuff on there I want to get off.  If there is any way you know how to mount that drive by either another ubuntu instance or in windows I would love to know.